# Iterating through array - java

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if it was better to have a method for this and pass the `Array` to that method or to write it out every time I want to check if a number is in the `array`.

For example:

```
public static boolean inArray(int[] array, int check) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == check) 
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should definitely encapsulate this logic into a method.

There is no benefit to repeating identical code multiple times.

Also, if you place the logic in a method and it changes, you only need to modify your code in one place.

Whether or not you want to use a 3rd party library is an entirely different decision.

Answer (score 53):

Since atleast Java 1.5.0 (Java 5) the code can be cleaned up a bit. `Array`s and anything that implements `Iterator` (e.g. `Collection`s) can be looped as such:

```
public static boolean inArray(int[] array, int check) {
   for (int o : array){
      if (o == check) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

In Java 8 you can also do something like:

```
// import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public static boolean inArray(int[] array, int check) {
   return IntStream.of(array).anyMatch(val -> val == check);
}
```

Although converting to a stream for this is probably overkill.

Comment: The java-8 version is incorrect, Arrays.asList(array) will yield a List<int[]> with a single element and that is the array which is not the intention. Also a list doesn’t have an anyMatch method. Look into Arrays.stream or IntStream.of

Comment: Thanks @Aominè - fixed.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using an array (and purely an array), the lookup of "contains" is `O(N)`, because worst case, you must iterate the entire array.  Now if the array is sorted you can use a binary search, which reduces the search time to `log(N)` with the overhead of the sort.

If this is something that is invoked repeatedly, place it in a function:

```
private boolean inArray(int[] array, int value)
{  
     for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
     {
        if (array[i] == value) 
        {
            return true;
        }
     }
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: How is that different that the function in the original post?  Also, as a personal request, braces are a great thing for people learning the language.

Comment: @JustinKSU  +1 for suggesting to _always_ use braces for if statements and for loops.  And yes, the above code is identical to the OPs code.

Comment: @JustinKSU just copy/pasted the OP's post (which is why there were no braces).  Added the function to be the same as there was no change needed and it served to answer OP's two part question.

Answer (score 7):

You can import the lib org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils

There is a static method where you can pass in an int array and a value to check for.

contains(int[] array, int valueToFind) 
          Checks if the value is in the given array.

```
ArrayUtils.contains(intArray, valueToFind);
```

[ArrayUtils API](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using java 8 Stream API could simplify your job.

```
public static boolean inArray(int[] array, int check) {
    return Stream.of(array).anyMatch(i -> i == check);
}
```

It's just you have the overhead of creating a new `Stream` from `Array`, but this gives exposure to use other `Stream` API. In your case you may not want to create new method for one-line operation, unless you wish to use this as utility.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Don’t use Stream.of as it will not do what you think it does in this specific case, instead use IntStream.of or Arrays.stream.

Comment: `Arrays.stream(a).anyMatch(i -> i == check);`
@Aominè Can you give example for how we can use `IntStream.of` ?

Comment: IntStream.of(array).anyMatch(i-> i ==check); or Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch(i-> i ==check);

Comment: `IntStream.of` takes in `int` not `array`, any other way to get IntStream?

Comment: why don’t you just run the code I’ve suggested against yours and see which one works.