# Split an array into two arrays via them types

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, split

How can I write a program to input a string (consisting of symbols and numbers)
into an array? The program then should store numbers into Array1,
and symbols into Array2.

For example I want to input a `String` like: `Im 18 years old & 22 days` to an array like `[Im 18 years old & 22 days]` and then convert it to two arrays:

```
[Im,years,old,days] and [18,&,22]
```

Comment: That’s a lot to ask in one Stack Overflow question. Please break your assignment into pieces and ask individual questions about each one. How do I read input in Java? How do I break a string into pieces and store them in an array? How do I check if such a piece is a number or a symbol? How do I create a new array? How do I move pieces from the original array to the new one?

Comment: Also please remember to search and research before asking. And to report what your search brought up and how it fell short of solving your problem. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

This is an approach, but I'm not sure if this is the best one:

1. Split String on space (based on your example text) : [How to split a String by space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899525/how-to-split-a-string-by-space)
2. Iterate through the array, returned by the split method. : [Iterating through array - java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489590/iterating-through-array-java)
3. For each element, determine if its text or just a number. (maybe using regex or worse, using logic that based on catching a numberformatexception) : [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)
4. If string, add to 'Array1', if number, add to 'Array2' : [How to add new elements to an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843366/how-to-add-new-elements-to-an-array)